# Why is the "model" attributes in the Control.text of react-redux-form components below has a "." at the beginning of the value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux-form

Why is the "model" attributes in the Control.text has a "." at the beginning of the value? Looking at the official website of the react-redux-form it has not used "." in front of the value? See the example below.

```
<RowclassName='form-group'>
 <LabelhtmlFor='firstname'md={2}>First Name</Label>
 <Col md={10}>
   <Control.text model='.firstname'id='firstname'name='firstname'placeholder='First Name'/>
  </Col> 
</Row>
```

Comment: In your case, Is it working with and also without the "." ?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried the values name without "." in the beginning and it did NOT work. :(

Comment: Actually I have overlooked the example. It did use "." in front of the value. I would like to know what would that concept is called? Thanks

Comment: The "." is used to access to an object attribute. For example, if you have the object named user, and inside you have firstname and lastname, you can assign the control to "user.firstname" and/or "user.lastname"